# How to center a section containing unordered lists

Tags: css

I'm trying to center the section (`.provincia`) with which contains unordered lists.

I have tried a standard `margin: 0 auto` but it is not working as I expected.

How can I fix this?

Here is my Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F6hrC/

**CSS**

```
.poblaciones-container {
    width: 1400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.poblaciones {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.provincia {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="poblaciones-container">
<section class="poblaciones fila2">
  <div class="provincia">
    <ul>
      <h2>Soria</h2>
            <li>Cuellar</li><li>El Espinar</li>
            <li>Real Sitio de San Ildefonso</li><li>Palazuelos de Eresma</li>
            <li>Cantalejo</li><li>La Lastrilla</li>
            <li>Nava de la Asunción</li><li>San Cristobal de Segovia</li>
            <li>Carbonero del Mayor</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="provincia">
          <ul>
            <h2>Segovia</h2>
            <li>Almazán</li><li>Burgo de Osma</li>
            <li>Ólvega</li><li>San Esteban de Gormaz</li>
            <li>Ágreda</li><li>San Leonardo de Yague</li>
            <li>Golmayo</li><li>Covaleda</li>
            <li>Arcos de Jalón</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="provincia">
          <ul>
            <h2>Ávila</h2>
            <li>Arévalo</li><li>Arenas de San Pedro</li>
            <li>Las Navas del Marqués</li><li>Candeleda</li>
            <li>Sotillo de la Adrada</li><li>El Tiemblo</li>
            <li>Cebreros</li><li>La Adrada</li>
            <li>El Barco de Ávila</li><li>El Hoyo de Pinares</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center an element with `margin: 0 auto;` you need to specify the width of that element. Take a look at my fix [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F6hrC/5/).

Also you had a problem with clearing floats. I fixed it by adding a `clearfix` at the end of your lists.

If the width is fixed, it's alright but if you have a dynamic width you can use javascript to add the width of your element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/F6hrC/3/).

The CSS Changes:

```
ul > li{text-align:center;}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Sorry I misunderstood your question.

Here is the Solution.

```
.poblaciones-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.poblaciones {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this is using the `inline-block` display type instead of floats:

```
.poblaciones-container {
    width: 1400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.poblaciones {
    margin: 0 auto; /* not needed anymore... */
    overflow: auto; /*  prevent floated elements from overflowing parent */
    outline: 2px dotted gray;
    text-align: center; /* to center the .provincia inline-blocks */
}

.provincia {
    display: inline-block; /* inline-blocks respond to text-align property */
    vertical-align: top; /* align blocks to top edge of parent container */
    text-align: left; /* Keep the content left-aligned, probably a good idea */
    margin-left: 20px; /* may be optional... */
    width: 300px;
    outline: 2px  dashed blue;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/4q7sb/

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to set a width to `.poblaciones` and you can add other lists without changing the CSS or the HTML.